# Autocomplete dropdown is not displayed properly

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, asp.net-core, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I try to use the jquery-ui autocomplete combobox in a .NeCore 2.2 web app.
It seems that I have a problem with the CSS. Here how it looks like:
[image]

beside the jquery-ui css, I use also datatables css and bootstrap css.
Also this style is used:

```
<style>

.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index: 1000 /*show the dropdown over the addform*/
}
```

html is this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label id="PersonIdLable" class="custom-label">Choose Person</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input id="PersonId" class="form-control" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input id="PersonName" class="form-control text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" asp-action="ttCreate"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>New Transaction</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

java script key down event is this:

```
       $('#PersonId').keydown(function () {
        //table = table.ajax.reload();
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Household/getPersonsJson2/",
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        search_str: request.term
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        //console.log(data);
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            appendTo: "#dialog-form",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                //console.log(ui.item.label + " " + ui.item.value);
                $("#PersonName").val(ui.item.label);
            },
            open: function () {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
            },
            close: function () {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: are you getting the suggestion places in console? Is the problem that they are being showed in the DOM?

Comment: yes, I get the data in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. The issue was that the action returned wrong field names. The names must be "value" and  "label". The action looks now like this:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> getPersonsJson2(string search_str)
    {
        var persons = await (from p in _context.Persons
                             where p.FullNameWithPLN.ToLower().Contains(search_str.ToLower())
                             select new
                             {
                                 value = p.Id,
                                 label = p.FullNameWithPLN
                             }).OrderBy(a => a.label).ToListAsync();

        return Json(persons);
    }
```